# Oldie but Goldie

Tags: word, wordplay

*You’ve probably seen this one before...*

> 1. Review a loot box
> 2. Sichuan restaurant tagline
> 3. “Release your inner personality!”
> 4. Hogwarts student exchange program
> 5. Firefighter’s directive
> 6. Angsty fish
> 7. Await a turnover
> 8. Exxon job

The answer is **a single word.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining the answers from tmpearce and arbitrahj to get the whole thing:

> Chestnut - Old, gold and you've heard it before.

Individual clues:

> 1. (C)rate
> 2. (H)eat
> 3. (E)go
> 4. (S)witch
> 5. (T)rain or maybe (T)hose 
> 6. (N)emo
> 7. (U)pend
> 8. (T)oil

Comment: The title likely references this usage of the word: [spoiler](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/gathering-chestnuts).

Comment: Yep, @noedne is correct; same goes for the flavortext. BTW there’s a better solution to #5 that I’m thinking of, but the rest of them are correct

Comment: I also considered (G)ubfr (rot13), if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @MatthewBarber That’s the one! I wrote the puzzle in a few minutes, so some of the clues were a bit weak. Perhaps a better clue would’ve been something like rot13(pne jnfure’f pbzznaq). In any case, I’ll give you the check mark after a day or so, so stay tuned for that!

Answer (score 5):

Very Partial start to an answer:

> **_ _ _ S _ N _ T**

```
1   Review a loot box
```

> Can Scan ??

```
2   Sichuan restaurant tagline
```

> 

```
3   “Release your inner personality!”
```

> Ego LEGO ??? Id rid???

```
4   Hogwarts student exchange program
```

> Witch Switch

```
5   Firefighter’s directive
```

> 

```
6   Angsty fish
```

> Emo Nemo

```
7   Await a turnover
```

> 

```
8   Exxon job
```

> Oil Toil

Answer (score 4):

Possible partial answers:

`1   Review a loot box`

> Rate Crate (C)

`2   Sichuan restaurant tagline`

> Eat Heat (H)

`3   Release your inner personality`

> Go Ego (E)

`5   Firefighter's directive`

> Pray Spray (S)

`6   Await a turnover`

> Pend Upend (U)